# Comparing two numbers in sage

Tags: python, numbers, numeric, sage

i would like to know why by comparing two real numbers (e.g. `bool(r1 == r2)`) in sage cas online it returns wrong boolean values.

E.g.§1:

```
(x,y,z)=var('x,y,z');
x=2
r1= (sin(x)).n()
r2= (sin(x)).n(digits=3)
print r1, type(r1)
print r2, type(r2)
bool(r1==r2)
```

0.909297426825682  ==
0.909 
True

But E.g.§2

```
(x,y,z)=var('x,y,z');
x=2
r1= (sin(x)).n()
r2= (0.909).n(digits=3)
print r1, type(r1)
print r2, type(r2)
bool(r1==r2)
```

0.909297426825682  ==
0.909 
False

Or e.g.§3

```
(x,y,z)=var('x,y,z');
x=2
r1= 0.909297426825682.n(digits=3)
r2= (0.909).n(digits=3)
print r1, type(r1)
print r2, type(r2)
bool(r1==r2)
```

0.909  ==
0.909 
False

In my project I would like to compare user answer which can be rounded e.g. to 3 decimal places with 53 bits CAS-solution solution which can be both symbolic and numeric values. Thanx

Comment: If you want to compare numbers, subtract them and compare the difference to zero. If the difference is close enough to zero for your purposes, treat them as equal.

Comment: Also, I would suggest posting Sage questions at https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/: it will get more attention there.

Answer (score 0):

First note that declaring x,y,z to be variables is not what you want, because that is a symbolic variable; you can just do `x=2` without prelude.  That is not really relevant, but helpful, I hope.

As to your question, your numbers are actually subtly different.  The way they print out is not the internal representation.

```
sage: s1= (sin(x)).n()
....: s2= (sin(x)).n(digits=3)
sage: r1= (sin(x)).n()
....: r2= (0.909).n(digits=3)
....: 
sage: s2 == r2
False
sage: s2 - r2
0.000305
sage: s2.sign_mantissa_exponent()
(1, 14898, -14)
sage: r2.sign_mantissa_exponent()
(1, 14893, -14)
```

You can see that they are represented slightly differently by the computer, presumably due to the original difference

```
sage: sin(2.)
0.909297426825682
sage: 0.909
0.909000000000000
```

Whereas

```
sage: r1 - s1
0.000000000000000
```

The way in which the digit precision works is not exactly the same as just truncation, and preserves a little extra info to keep things accurate.

Moral: Be very careful with numerical work unless you really understand that real numbers aren't the same as what's in the computer.  Luckily, for most practical purposes John's comments will serve you just fine, or else I'd be in trouble, as someone who is definitely not a numerical analyst.